# Haskell, Emacs and El Capitan: ghc-7.10.2 already installed, it's just not linked

Tags: haskell, emacs, ghc, cabal, osx-elcapitan

I upgraded to El Capitan and now Haskell in emacs is no longer working. I got ghc working in the terminal as well as cabal. However, it was recommended to use homebrew for ghc and when I do the following:

```
brew install ghc
```

I get the following warning:

```
Warning: ghc-7.10.2 already installed, it's just not linked
```

Furthermore, when I try loading in emacs it says the following

```
searching for program: no such file or directory, cabal
```

And then when the interpreter loads, it doesn't let me hit RETURN key

Comment: where have you installed ghc/haskell? I think you just have to include the location of the bins to your path and you are fine...

Comment: which ghc returns: /Applications/ghc-7.10.2.app/Contents/bin/ghc and my path is /Users/astiefel/.local/bin:/Users/astiefel/.cabal/bin:/Applications/ghc-7.10.2.app/Contents/bin:/Users/astiefel/Library/Haskell/bin:/Users/astiefel/Library/Haskell/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/Users/astiefel/bin/Sencha/Cmd/4.0.2.67:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools:/opt/local:/opt/local/bin

Comment: Are you able to run ghc from the command line? The bin directory seems to be in your path.